# Passing joined table to razor view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, razor

I'm new to the MVC architecture and I have the following Controller that's joining two tables:

```
Public Class ProblemsController
    Inherits Controller
    Private db As New dbECRMEntities
    ' GET: Problems
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim q = (From pb In db.Problem_History Join pbs In db.Problems On pb.problem_id Equals pbs.problem_id)
        Return View(q.AsEnumerable)
    End Function
End Class
```

How should I set the `@ModelType` in the view in order to reference the values in q? My project name is ECRM and I can't seem to get VS2013 to recognize anything when I type in `ECRM.Models`

Joining tables seems to be giving me a lot more trouble than I initially would've thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for your return type if you don't already have one (simple example here)

```
Public Class YourClass
    Public ExampleValue As String
End Class
```

Then change the code in your controller to this

```
Public Class ProblemsController
    Inherits Controller
    Private db As New dbECRMEntities
    ' GET: Problems
    Function Index() As ActionResult
    Dim q = (From pb In db.Problem_History Join pbs In db.Problems On pb.problem_id Equals pbs.problem_id
         Select New YourClass With {.ExampleValue = pb.ExampleValue})
    Return View(q.AsEnumerable)
    End Function
End Class
```

And set the Model type in the view like so

```
@ModelType List(Of MvcApplication1.ExampleClass)
```